# Why molar volume takes range of values along triple line whereas the temperature and pressure are constant along this line?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

In the P-V-T surface the triple line is the line parallel to P-V plane on which three states of matter are in equilibrium. Temperature and pressure are same at all points along the triple line. But we know that the value of one of the three state variables(pressure, temperature, molar volume) will be specified if other two state variables are specified. If we specify two state variables then the third state variable can't take range of values. But along the triple line for specific temperature and pressure there is range of values for molar volume. Can anyone explain why? Maybe I am missing something obvious.

Comment: The molar volume of solid, liquid, and gas phase at the triple point are different.  So, depending on the proportions that the three phases are present, the average molar volume of the combination will vary.

Comment: @ChetMiller But why the proportion of the three phases different, if they have same temperature and pressure. I mean to say if we keep the temperature and pressure constant there would not be any phase change i.e some solid converted into liquid or liquid converted to gas, so the proportion will be always same and the average molar volume is same. Also it will be great if you give an elaborate answer or refer to some material online which addresses this particular question(I couldn't find one). Thanks.

Comment: When a vapor and liquid are at equilibrium above the triple point, do we always have equal amounts of vapor and liquid?